# giraffe routef async function

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe

I've been creating a Giraffe api server using f# and have happily been using the `route` functions:

```ml
type Person = { id: BsonObjectId; name: string; age: int; }

let getPeople (databaseFn: unit-> IMongoDatabase) : HttpHandler =
    fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) -> 
        let database = databaseFn()
        let collection = database.GetCollection<Person> "people"
        task {
            let! cursor = collection.FindAsync<Person>(fun p -> true)
            let! hasMoved = cursor.MoveNextAsync()
            let result = 
                match hasMoved with
                | true -> json cursor.Current next ctx
                | false -> 
                    let message = { message = "No People found" }
                    RequestErrors.notFound (json message) next ctx
            return! result
        }

let savePerson (databaseFn: unit -> IMongoDatabase ) : HttpHandler =
    fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) -> 
        let database = databaseFn()
        let collection = database.GetCollection<Person> "people"
        task {
            let serialiser = ctx.GetJsonSerializer()
            let! person = ctx.BindJsonAsync<Person>()
            let personWithId = { person with id = BsonObjectId ( ObjectId.GenerateNewId() ) }
            do! collection.InsertOneAsync(personWithId)
            return! text "nailed it" next ctx
        }

let deletePerson (databaseFn: unit -> IMongoDatabase ) = 
    fun (id: string) -> 
        let database = databaseFn()
        let collection = database.GetCollection<Person> "people"
        task {
            let oId = BsonObjectId (ObjectId id) 
            let! result = collection.FindOneAndDeleteAsync<Person>(fun p -> p.id = oId)
            return text "awesomesauce"
        }

let personHandler getPeople savePerson deletePerson = 
    let path = "/people"
    choose [
        GET >=> choose [
            route path >=> getPeople
        ]
        POST >=> choose [
            route path >=> savePerson
        ]
        DELETE >=> choose [
            routef "/people/%s" >=> deletePerson
        ]
    ]
```

But I've add the `deletePerson` handler but it's now complaining that

```ml
routef "/people/%s" >=> deletePerson
```

> The type 'HttpFuncResult' does not match the type 'HttpHandler'

I get that the types don't match, but when I use it like so

```ml
routef "/people/%s" deletePerson
```

it complains that the `deletePerson` function returns `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<(HttpFunc -> HttpContext -> HttpFuncResult)>` instead of a `HttpHandler`

I'm just not sure how I have a `routef` where I can get the value from the route parameter and have an async HttpHandler in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have all the types imported to make the whole thing compile, but I think you need to remove the `>=>` from the delete:

```
DELETE >=> choose [
   (routef "/people/%s" deletePerson)
]
```

And the deletePerson signature would be:

```
let deletePerson (databaseFn: unit -> IMongoDatabase ) (id: string) : HttpHandler = 
    fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) -> 
        let database = databaseFn()
        //etc
```

Comment: yeah, I seemed to have forgotten about partially applying the deletePerson function! But none of the docs even seems to have an example like that... but probably more my missunderstanding of the type